# Scrolling instead of anchoring

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

My website is only one page, and I would like it to scroll down to the two/three sections I have instead of jumping to the anchor. Any help would be great.

HTML:

```
<nav id="header-navigation" class="sixteen columns" role="navigation">

<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#header-global" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#latest-work" title="Our Work">Startups</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

</nav><!-- end #header-navigation -->
```

So do I just add a .js file somewhere? Do I add the following code in my HTML?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollTo(target) {
    var targetPosition = $(target).offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: targetPosition
    }, 'slow');
}
</script>
```

My site is pinstart.us

Comment: @AlexW The code posted in the question clearly uses jQuery

Comment: Tried reading that question....just not sure where/how to put in all that JQuery code...

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: Thanks Dom, figured it out!